# slack で直近のnotificationに含まれるリンクをショートカットで開きたい

Tags: google-chrome, github, slack

github で assign されたら pr のリンクが通知される環境で、
通知が来る＞マウスで画面右上に出た通知をクリックしてslackを開く＞リンクをクリックしてブラウザで開く
というのが面倒です。

できるだけ楽をしたいのですが、（アサインされたらブラウザが開くとか、キーボードだけで完結できるとか）

なにか良い方法はないでしょうか？